# C#: Windows 10, putting a big tile icon on the start menuto launch a regular exe

Tags: c#, wpf

using c#I need to create a shortcut for a a regular application using a tile. As seen in the screenshot the objective is for my tile to be like the bigger tiles on the right hand of the expanded start menu. Is it possible to create my own group such as 'Key' instead of placing into "Play and Explore" and "Life at a Glance"

[image: win 10]